# Qt and C++ how to share items from classes

Tags: c++, qt, qtimer

My problem is: I'm using an example made by Qt as educational (it's a terminal to send and receive serial data). I need to create a QTimer starting in a function built in a class and stop it in another function built in a different class.
Qtimer obviously works with no problem in function declared in the same class where Timer is; but it remains unknown in the class built to the other class.
How can I solve?

Comment: Perhaps do some research about *shared pointers* (like e..g [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr))?

Comment: you can use the SIGNAL, SLOT for that, I think this is the QT-est way to solve that issue

Comment: You can also set your timer public, or declare B as a friend class for your timer... but it's generally seen as a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the Qt SIGNAL / SLOT system. Then you may have something like that:

```
class A : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
//...
public slots:
    stopTimerHandler() {timer.stop();}
private:
    QTimer timer;
};

class B : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
//...
private:
    stopTimer() {emit stopTimerSig();}
signals:
    stopTimerSig();
};

// somewhere
A a;
B b;
connect(&b, SIGNAL(stopTimerSig()), &a, SLOT(stopTimerHandler())); // old connect version
// or ( ty @eyllanesc for the new syntax ) 
QObject::connect(&b, &B::stopTimerSig, &a, &A::stopTimerHandler); // qt5
```

B emit a signal listened by A, when A receive the signal, A stops his timer.

Comment: Use new-syntax: `QObject::connect(&b, &B::topTimerSig, &a, &A::stopTimerHandler);`, https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

Comment: @eyllanesc ty for this suggestion, I've added it in my answer. I still let the old connect version because OP didn't specify his qt version.

Comment: When you specify the version of a library you must assume the latest version.